# Shuffle through a series of photos using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Lets say I had 10 pictures and I wanted to go through them in kind of like a facebook style layout, where I could just click an arrow and it would bring me to the next one. I guess I want to try to do this with Jquery or javascript for practice.

How would I go about doing this?

I assume in some way it would be like 'on click of this button load the next picture, and get rid of the old one'. I guess that is one way of trying it but how would you go about it?

Comment: Search for jquery lightbox...

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html) LOADS of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var images = new Array(//series of image urls);
var index = 0;
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
  index++;
  var nextimage = images[index];
  $("#imageid").attr("src",nextImage);
});
```

If you would like a more thorough explanation, just ask.